# Calling a script file on a remote server

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that I need to execute a script file (no functions) on another server. I am using invoke-command for this but I cannot seem to get this to work correctly and execute the script on the remote server.

I don't have any code examples with me but what's the way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of the script on the remote server? Is that also a powershell script?

Comment: You want someone to post the help examples for `Invoke-Command`? Because .. nobody can post anything more appropriate to get around the problems you're having if you don't explain what those problems are that need fixing. The way to do it is to have (appropriate windows versions, on a domain, appropriate WinRM config, Windows firewall config, network firewall config, use hostnames, use domain accounts, have the right permissions for remoting, have the right permissions to the filesystem, reference the file path correctly, have no syntax errors, except where any of these things don't apply..)

Comment: Ok so the account is a farm admin on the SharePoint server (can execute commands that are SharePoint-specific, etc), but get this warning: ERROR: Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is properly configured, currently available,

Comment: @dotnetdev Sounds like you may need to put the command in a scriptblock - [related TechNet post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1880b61f-851c-4895-acbb-a6cb757b24ee/powershell-remoting-cannot-access-the-local-farm?forum=sharepointadmin)